# When should one set the staircase is True when decaying the learning rate in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Recall that when [exponentially decaying](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#decaying-the-learning-rate) the learning rate in TensorFlow one does:

> decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
>                           decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)

the docs mention this staircase option as:

> If the argument staircase is True, then global_step /decay_steps is an
>   integer division and the decayed learning rate follows a staircase
>   function.

when is it better to decay every X number of steps and follow at stair case function rather than a smoother version that decays more and more with every step?

Comment: I came looking with the same question and found this as well as the feature request which might shine a light: [staircase feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2432) Specifically: "Right now for learning rates we have exponential_decay, which is useful but doesn't handle fine-tuned scheduling. For example, regardless of whether we did this manually or with exponential_decay, there'd be boilerplate code to use a learning rate of 1.0 for 100000 steps, 0.5 for the next 10000 steps, and 0.1 for all remaining steps." What (I think) they are saying is that there may be rou

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers didn't seem to describe this. There are two different behaviors being described as 'staircase' behavior.

- From the [feature request for staircase](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2432), the behavior is described as being a hand-tuned piecewise constant decay rate, so that a user could provide a set of iteration boundaries and a set of decay rates, to have the decay rate jump to the specified value after the iterations pass a given boundary.

  If you look into the [actual code for this feature pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2442/files), you'll see that the PR isn't related much to the staircase option in the function arguments. Instead, it defines a wholly separate `piecewise_constant` operation, and the associated unit test shows how to define your own custom learning rate as a piecewise constant with `learning_rate_decay.piecewise_constant`.
- From [the documentation on decaying the learning rate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay), the behavior is described as treating `global_step / decay_steps` as integer division, so for the first set of `decay_steps` steps, the division results in 0, and the learning rate is constant. Once you cross the `decay_steps`-th iteration, you get the decay rate raised to a power of 1, then a power of 2, etc. So you only observe decay rates at the particular powers, rather than smoothly varying across all the powers if you treated the global step as a float.

As to advantages, this is just a hyperparameter decision you should make based on your problem. Using the staircase option allows you hold a decay rate constant, essentially like maintaining a higher temperature in simulated annealing for a longer time. This can allow you explore more of the solution space by taking bigger strides in the gradient direction, at the cost of possible noisy or unproductive updates. Meanwhile, smoothly increasing the decay rate power will steadily "cool" the exploration, which can limit you by making you stuck near a local optimum, but it can also prevent you from wasting time with noisily large gradient steps.

Whether one approach or the other is better (a) often doesn't matter very much and (b) usually needs to be specially tuned in the cases when it might matter.

Separately, as the feature request link mentions, the piecewise constant operation seems to be for very specifically tuned use cases, when you have separate evidence in favor of a hand-tuned decay rate based on collecting training metrics as a function of iteration. I would generally not recommend that for general use.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

For all I know it is preference of the research group.

Back from the old times, it was computationally more efficient to reduce the learning rate only every epoch. That's why some people prefer to use it nowadays.

Another, hand-wavy, story that people may tell is it prevents from local optima. By "suddenly" changing the learning rate, the weights might jump to a better bassin. (I don;t agree with this, but add it for completeness)

Comment: why don't u agree with the hand wavy story?